# Redhat CDK could not find matching ip for mac windows/vpn software

Tags: openshift, redhat-containers

Question: How do I get CDK to work on the corporate laptop using virtualbox without running into the 'could not find mathcing ip for mac' issue?

environment: Windows7, CDK 3.2.0, Virtualbox 5.0.x/5.1.x various versions tried.  Key callout, corporate machine has VPN software (cisco anyconnect) while home pc does not, home pc works fine.  Issue happens regardless if using VPN or not.  Virtualbox (all versions) proven to work using vagrant.

Key finding:

```
minishift ssh -> functions, doing an ifconfig returns eth0 with a 10.0.* 
network, instead of the expected 192.168.99.* network segments configured 
for virtualbox network host adapters. Explicitly using minishift config set 
host-only-cidr 192.168.99.1/24 with matching virtualbox host adapters 
doesn't change outcome
```

Details:

```
c:\devrh\cdk\bin>minishift version 

minishift v1.7.0+204ce19 CDK v3.2.0-1


c:\devrh\cdk\bin>minishift start --vm-driver=virtualbox -- Starting local 
OpenShift cluster using 'virtualbox'
hypervisor ... -- Starting Minishift VM ............................ FAIL 
E1108 10:27:05.991687 3128 start.go:356] Error starting the VM: Error 
configuring authorization on host: Could not find matching IP for MAC 
address 0800279fa156. Retrying. Error starting
the VM: Error configuring authorization on host: Could not find matching IP 
for MAC address 0800279fa156
```

corporate workstation has the issue, home PC does not.

Minishift delete and restart, same issue (different MAC address, but same issue).

Virtualbox remove all host adapters, minishift delete, restart (which auto-creates new host adapters), same issue.

Minishift --profile approach, same issue.

Uninstalled virtualbox, installed the version from the RHDevSuite installer with the CDK from the installer, all steps tested with that combination as well, same issue.

Additional notes, Virtualbox is working fine with vagrant (static IP’s in vagrant files), virtualbox/vagrant combo works on both corporate and home machine without issues.

Comment: minishift ip -> Error Getting IP: could not find matching IP for MAC address XXXXXXX

Comment: minishift ssh -> functions, doing an ifconfig returns eth0 with a 10.0.* network, instead of the expected 192.168.99.* network segments configured for virtualbox network host adapters. Explicitly using minishift config set host-only-cidr 192.168.99.1/24 with matching virtualbox host adapters doesn't change outcome.